# How to run an Observable several times and concat its results correctly?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I have this observable that produces JSON, really an API which returns text from different books.
I need to call this observable several times and concatenate the results in the *correct order*.
I have derived a playground code at stackblitz please use it to derive a solution answer, but I will accept inline code as well.

If you could provide two solutions one running the observable calls in parallel and sequentially, that would be great. Perhaps it will light up the bulb inside my head.  If they run in parallel I need the results to be organized sequentially by BookIndex.

I have read many blogs, rxjs docs, and SO pages on Observables and Promises but it's a topic that does not sink in and a source of continuous struggle. I have also attempted to convert Observable to promise via toPromise() but it did not lead me to success.  On the searches I've done before this post on Observable I see mentions of .concact and joinFork, however I don't know how to apply them to derive a solution.

Here is some of the code I am struggling with.  Calling BuildAndShow() seems to produce the calls to the observable, as observed in the console, but I don't see the final result in the alert as if
"**await** MessagesBuild()" returned prematurely without waiting for completion of MessagesBuild().

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-k8t49r?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.ts

```
 // uses a class member/field to build strings into it
 // can it be written to use a local then return it?
  async MessagesBuild() {
    this.Messages_ = "";
    for (let BookIndex = 0; BookIndex < 4; BookIndex++) {
      await this.RandomString(BookIndex).subscribe(data => {
        this.Messages_ += data + "\n";
        console.log(data);
      });
    }
    return this.Messages_;  // I have difficulty grasping how returns should be coded??
  }
  //
  async ShowLast() {
    alert(this.Messages);
  }
  //
  async BuildAndShow() {
    await this.MessagesBuild();
    alert(this.Messages);
  }
```

If my coding was correct

1. Pressing "**Build and Show Messages**" I would see the final concatenated strings in the alert.
2. Pressing "**Build Async Messages**" would have updated the bound view to display the final result not just the first page.

[image]

What can you assume about me:

1. After 4 years at this all I understand is that promise.then(() =>{...}) and observable.subscribe(() =>{...}) execute when they complete.
2. I am learning the hard way that sprinkling this syntactic sugar of async/await randomly ain't solving this asynchronous world.

--Thank you. Your help is immensely appreciated.

**UPDATE 1:**

I have incorporated @Nenad Milosavljevic answer in the following stackblitz
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-wkplkm?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.ts

The  "**Build and Show Messages**"  is working.
However, not sure about "**Build Async Messages**" it appears Angular is not able to call a method returning Promise so I have added BuildOnly() : string.
Results (Angular bound) don't seem to be updating in the view.

Check it out.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-wkplkm?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.ts

**If you happen to know of a solution using observable only (no promises) I would be curious to know how simple or ugly it looks :)  Thank you.

**UPDATE 2:**

One way to make Nenad's solution update the view, requires triggering the change detect manually. I dug up an import line from 2018 :) do you think I can pop this junk from the back of my cortex just like that?.

import { ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core'; // 20180129

like so

[image]

Trevor's solution uses ngZone.run to achieve the same (though I could not call it automatic Angular change detection).

Answer (score 2):

Ok, let's go one by one.

```
async BuildAndShow() {
    await this.MessagesBuild();
    alert(this.Messages);
}
```

Here, you can not `await` for `this.MessagesBuild()` since it is not returning `Promise` (you can but it won't have any effect). So, that means that you have to refactor `this.MessagesBuild()` to return a `Promise`.

Also, in `this.MessagesBuild()` the `await` will also have no effect since it `this.RandomString` is an `Observable` and not the `Promise`. What you can do is change it to `Promise` with `toPromise()` method. You can create one `Promise` for each of the `bookData` that you are waiting for. After that you can use `Promise.all()` function that will take as an input all `Promises` that you are waiting for, and it will resolve only after all `Promises` resolves. After that you will have a result of all `Promises` which you can use to construct `this.Messages_`. After that you can `resolve` with `this.Messages_` so it will be available in `BuildAndShow()`.

The code will look link this:

```
import "rxjs/add/operator/toPromise";

...

MessagesBuild() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let message_result = ""
    let promises = [];
    for (let BookIndex = 0; BookIndex < 4; BookIndex++) {
      promises.push(this.RandomString(BookIndex).toPromise());
    }
    Promise.all(promises).then((results) => {
      results.forEach((result) => {
        message_result = message_result + result;
      });
      resolve(message_result);
    });
  })
}
```

And now you can refactor `BuildAndShow()` to wait for `this.MessagesBuild()` to resolve, and to set the value of `this.Messages`.

```
 async BuildAndShow() {
    let messages = await this.MessagesBuild();
    alert(messages);
  }
```

Here is the link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-iqsqsy?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.ts

Comment: I think I am following your thoughts, I have used a similar construct of promise tasks before to chain sound clips.  I have tried to copy and paste your solution but it's not happy about MessageBuild() returning promise unknown.  Could you please check it here, I am sure it's something simple for you.  Thank you. https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-iqsqsy?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.ts

Comment: You have to add `import "rxjs/add/operator/toPromise";` as import. And also, `resolve(message_result);` has to be inside the `Promise.all()`. I updated the answer, and updated the stackblitz code so you can check it.

Comment: Since he used `async` for `this.MessagesBuild`, it would return a promise and `await` would work.

Comment: I think I am going to have to accept your answer. BTW, I think stackblitz must have forced you to fork, or so I think?. I can't see your changes unless you share a new link.  If you still have the link (in your history) please update the answer.  Let me know if there is a way to stay away from promises and use Observables only for a different approach.  Perhaps async/await require promises?   thanks.

Comment: Can you please update your answer with MessagesBuild() : Promise<string> { } otherwise there will be red line under tthis.Messages = await this.MessagesBuild();
It's not able to infer the return type.
The (Build and Show) is working but the Build only is not updating the view perhaps something wrong with my html template and angular binding or both. I am debugging.

Comment: I updated the answer with the stackblitz link. Check it and me know if it works on your end.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you can change MessagesBuild use the following:

```js
let data = await this.RandomString(BookIndex).toPromise();
```

since you can only await on a Promise.

Then you can concat the data with the following:

```js
this.ngZone.run(() => {
    this.Messages_ += data + "\n";
});
```

Using the `NgZone` dependency is necessary to cause updates to the page.

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-ua6jgt?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.ts) is my solution.

Note that this is a synchronous solution, since using `await` in the loop will block execution.

Comment: Can you double check that link you shared, it does not seem to have use of .ngZone.run, and the build messages only button is not reflecting results.
I have never run into NgZone :) sounds scary
Thanks

Comment: See line 53. I couldn't get the parallel solution working, but the synchronous does work.

Comment: Yes your "Build Synchronously" button is working as expected. Your "Build Asynchronously" does not appear to reach the console.log ?? and I am lost with the all the (await zip), pipe, map Oh my :)  thanks for trying, appreciated.

Comment: I looked at the basic angular "interpolation" as they call it in their docs and it says "Reading a component value should not change some other displayed value. The view should be stable throughout a single rendering pass." I don't think my Message() prop is violating this though it changes over time, I was thinking Angular would refresh as it rebuild/refresh the pages or am I wrong? and thus the need for this ngZone.run thingy?

Comment: there is this one application that grew sluggish (my poor programming) and I called detectChange() few time according to posts, though I found it ugly. I am going to have to read few time about ngzone to get perhaps a grasp of what's going on. The change detection is apparently not always automatic, contrary to my belief.
https://angular.io/guide/zone

Comment: I think the reason for it is because of the asynchronous nature that you desire of the function. The application can't wait forever for this function to complete because it'd defeat the purpose of async. If it wasn't an `async` function, the change detection would wait for it to finish and notice the difference in the value of the variable.

Comment: Comparing the current 2 solutions for MessagesBuild() side by side, I do like your approach for compactness though it ties me to yet another Angular specific. I've been considering whether to move away to Ionic/React or perhaps even drop Ionic :) I don't know if I will have any beans left the for task ;-).  I will be incorporating your approach and will see perhaps how I can display a visual cue (ionic spinner) to the user as the API calls may be lagging behind if user selects lots of books and references.  I will need some boolean of some sort.  Thank you.

Comment: Just to be clear, the way you are doing it with `async` and `await` is not within the Angular paradigm.